# DNS Domain Issue

Tags: dns-domain

we are maintaining our DNS account to GODaddy DNS Provider for our servers, Right now we have an problem, If some one have to register domain or sub-domain from any of other dns provider or godaddy dns provider it allow's to activated and those domains are pointing directly to our servers easily, how to avoid these kind of cases, how to restrict some other peoples have to register some illegal domains like (porn or some other sites) with our server ip, How to avoid this kind of problem,We need your help for this kind of case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not really a security question; it's more of a server configuration question.

Answer (score 1):

As @lucas said, there's really no way that you can stop someone registering a domain and then pointing an "A" record for it, at a server you control.

That said, if this is a problem for you, you could reconfigure your web server (or use something like a Web Application Firewall) to redirect traffic that hits the server from those domain names.

I'd recommend either redirecting it to a static page stating that the domain used has nothing to do with your company, or just redirect them to a 3rd party site, so the content from your server isn't shown with that domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, there is no way. A DNS name translates a domain to an IP, if I want to make a domain thiscompanysucks.com and point it to your IP address, then there is nothing you can do about it.